# Codeigniter, Facebook and Facebook's login "code" query variable

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, query-string, url-routing, facebook-php-sdk

We're trying to log users into our Codeigniter app with the PHP SDK, we're using segmented URIs and have no need for query strings so we've opted to not use them.  One of the problems it seems with CI and Facebook is passing a `redirect_uri` parameter to `getLoginUrl()` e.x.

```
public function login(){
    if(!$this->user){
        $this->data['loginUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://appdomain.com/users/login'
        ));
        $this->load->view('users/login', $this->data);
    }else{
        redirect('home/index');
    }
}
```

After logging into Facebook, the URI returned has a `code` query variable that CI doesn't like, it essentially breaks routing and displays a blank page.

```
http://appdomain.com/users/login/?code=dsfeoilkjd983274893hflksdfhhewhkdsiue8...
```

Even if I add `$route['users/login/(:any)'] = 'users/login';` to `routes.php`, I'm still redirected to a blank page.  `Since we are using getAccessToken()` to make API calls on the user's behalf, we don't need to use the `code` query var to exchange for an access token.  Is it possible to remove the query string completely, possibly in `MY_Controller`, before routing it to a `method/action`?

The only way I was able to bypass the problem is passing the default controller to the `redirect_uri` parameter, everything else won't route to the correct URI and just displays a blank page.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the query string with `.htaccess`. Not sure if it will work, but it should if the function does an actual redirect i.e. the login process is sending the user to `http://appdomain.com/users/login/?code=dsfeoilkjd983274893hflksdfhhewhkdsiue8...` which seems to be the case.

This `.htaccess` will (in addition to removing `index.php`) strip the query string and send the url `http://appdomain.com/users/login/?code=dsfeoilkjd983274893` to `http://appdomain.com/users/login/`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R,L]
```

The `R` on the last line is seemingly optional. If you leave it out, the URL will still display the querystring in the URL, but it won't get parsed. If you leave it in, it will not display the querystring in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  However this gives me an internal server error.  I'm removing the index.php file with .htaccess, I tested with and without `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`, same results

Comment: Updated the answer -- need `!=""` in the first line. Also adjusted the `[L]` as it will tell htaccess to stop parsing and won't parse the querystring Cond if it's below the other Rule.